# Closures in Go - declaring functions that take functions as parameters

Tags: go

I've been trying to figure out why this is not working but am not sure. The error in the sandbox is

```
main.go:16: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting )
```

Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type handler func(a func(b int))

func HandleSomething(h handler)  {
    //...
    //d := h(5)
//h(5)
    // ...
}

func main() {
    var foo int
    HandleSomething(handler(func(func(b int){
            fmt.Printf("debug: foo in main is %d and %d", foo, b)
    })))
}
```

Comment: Did you want: https://play.golang.org/p/IwuO7b5kPG ?

Comment: In particular, your `handler` type is "a function that takes a function that takes an `int`" which seems like an extra level of wrapping compared to your comment out calls of just `h(5)`.

Comment: If you *really* did want `func(func(int))` for some reason: https://play.golang.org/p/yRzZSuEXgs

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you for your comment. No I was trying to better understand closures. And yes I want a function that takes a function that takes an int. So am not looking for the code above, but something to the extent of    func(func(b int)

Comment: @DaveC can you please tell me why this isn't running http://play.golang.org/p/5tUhd4yi7K ?

Comment: @Marin compare the location of brackets in your code and in example who gave you DaveC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why it won't compile it might be helpful to pull your innermost function out into an argument as shown at https://play.golang.org/p/QPBturZ6GG

I think you are looking for something like the following, but it won't do much 
https://play.golang.org/p/2tEEwoZRC6

```
package main

import "fmt"

type handler func(a func(b int))

func HandleSomething(h handler) {
    //...
    //d := h(5)
    //h(5)
    // ...
}

func main() {
    var foo int
    HandleSomething(handler(func(a func(b int)) {
        //This doesn't make sense as you don't have access to b
        //fmt.Printf("debug: foo in main is %d and %d", foo, b)
        fmt.Printf("debug: foo in main is %d", foo)

        //You can call your function argument like
        a(6)
        a(7)
    }))
}
```

The following example might give you something more to play with

https://play.golang.org/p/BuxA8JXibG

Comment: Thank you Roma for all the examples. funcArg is deemed as not a type when you run the first example. But isn't funcArg (maps to func(b int) ) part of the type definition above?

Comment: The last example was perfect! That was exactly what I needed